# Java copying references in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object, reference

I am having trouble understanding what impact copying references causes on the data.
I have an array of objects. 
This array is an attribute of another object of a different class.

I need to sort the objects in the array by one of its attributes.

I am wondering what is the best and appropriate way of doing this.

Lets name the above:

```
class Group{
    Single [] one;
    public Group(){
        one = new Single[10]; //creating array of type Single. 
        //...for loop will assign new objects to each index of one.
```

Now I need to sort that array. How can I do so? If I create a new array, sort it, then how would I save it back as an attribute of the Group object?

Can do do something like this?:

```
Single [] sorted=new Single [10];
Single [] sorted=new Single [10];
sorted[0] = one[2];
sorted[1] = one[4];//....
//and then overwrite one?
one = sorted //pardon me for the syntax.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
sorted[0] = one[2];
```

Since `sorted[0]` and `one[2]` contains the same object reference, if you alter the state of this reference in one of the arrays, then this change is *reflected* in the other array as well.

When you do this:

```
one = sorted
```

You're not modifying any object in the arrays, but changing the value of `one` variable.

Since you want/need to sort an array, there's no need to use an alternate array. Instead, do the sorting in the same array.

If you're just worried about how to sort the array, use `Arrays#sort(Comparator<? extends Single>)`. Otherwise, use your own sorting algorithm in this array rather than using a new array (unless you want/need to work with immutable elements).

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach, you can use [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to sort an array in place, i.e., the order of the elements in the array will change. You will need to provide a `Comparator<Single>` for that to work properly.

I recommend you try that and post code if you can't make it work (in a separate question).

Answer (score 0):

As you want the array in an object to be sorted, its better to do in-place sort of the array using **[Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)**. You **don't need to** create a new array and copy references into the new array and assign the new array reference to the original array reference again (as present in your example) as it causes wastage of space.